# Hide terminal buffer from buffer list

Tags: terminal, hidden-buffers

How do I keep the terminal buffer from showing up in my airline list of buffers?
I assume airline just pulls buffers from what normally shows up in :ls. But I actually don't want the terminal to show up in that list.

As you can see in this image there's an airline s "tab" to the right of the settings.json "tab" (airline has a setting to show buffers as tabs). This s tab is the terminal buffer that I had opened earlier with neoterm mapping for :botright Ttoggle. However, I really do not want this to show up in my list of buffers that I can tab through.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to get me what I want. I think neoterm relies on the terminal buffer being in the buffer list. I just made my buffer tab cycle key mapping check to see if the new buffer that was cycled to was the terminal buffer, if so do another bnext/bprev. Also needed an autocmd for getting into and out of insert mode depending on buftype. Airline has a var you can set for not displaying the terminal buffer to the buffer 'tabs'

```
    let g:airline#extensions#tabline#ignore_bufadd_pat = 'gundo|undotree|vimfiler|tagbar|nerd_tree|startify|!|term'

    au BufEnter * if &buftype == 'terminal' | startinsert | else | stopinsert | endif
    function! PrevBufferTab()
      bprev
      if &buftype == 'terminal'
        bprev
      endif
    endfunction
    function! NextBufferTab()
      bnext
      if &buftype == 'terminal'
        bnext
      endif
    endfunction
    " Cycle buffer tabs in airline's tab bar
    nnoremap <c-a> :call PrevBufferTab()<cr>
    nnoremap <c-x> :call NextBufferTab()<cr>
    " kill buffer tab
    nnoremap <c-q> :bp <bar> bd #<cr>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I added also the `quickfix` buffer to be skipped with 
`if &buftype == 'terminal' || &buftype == 'quickfix'`