# Show terminal buffer in airline's tabline

Tags: neovim, plugin-airline

I use airline's tabline to show a list of my current buffers:

```
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1 " Use the airline tabline (replacement for buftabline)
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#show_tab_nr = 1
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#tab_nr_type = 1 " tab number
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#excludes = ['branches', 'index']
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#buffer_idx_mode = 1
nmap <a-1> <Plug>AirlineSelectTab1
nmap <a-2> <Plug>AirlineSelectTab2
...
```

[image: airline's tabline]

I really enjoy moving between my buffers in this way.

I'd like to have a terminal buffer to, which shows up in this list as normal.

However, unlike [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20751/hide-terminal-buffer-from-buffer-list) which complains about the opposite problem, my terminal buffer(s) *don't* show up in airline's tabline.

They're in `ls` as `32 %aR  "term://.//30852:/usr/bin/zsh" line 1`.

How can I get my tabline to show these buffers too?

I'm using NVIM v0.4.2.

Comment: airline maintainer here: Terminal buffers are excluded from the tabline as mentioned in the help https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/blob/master/doc/airline.txt#L393-L403 you need to customize `g:airline#extensions#tabline#ignore_bufadd_pat`

Comment: Nice! Thanks so much. Is there a nice way to leave `ignore_bufadd_pat` as it is but remove `term://` or should I just "hard-code" the remaining definitions?

Comment: Seems to me you need to spell it all out. More importantly, don't you want to exclude  `!` ...  _The "!" prevents terminal buffers to appear in the tabline._

Comment: copy it from the help and remove the `term://` for neovim or the `!` for Vim

Comment: Thanks all. Got it working. If anyone wants to write these comments up into an answer, I'll happily accept and upvote!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per `:help airline`, the default value of things airline will filter out of the buffer list if not otherwise specified by the user is:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#ignore_bufadd_pat = '!|defx|gundo|nerd_tree|startify|tagbar|term://|undotree|vimfiler'
```

...where `!` and `term:/` are the respective ways of identifying terminals in VIM and Neovim respectively. Setting a value in your rc/init file that specifically excludes those should do the trick:

```
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#ignore_bufadd_pat = 'defx|gundo|nerd_tree|startify|tagbar|undotree|vimfiler'
```

Do note that if any excludes are later added to airline's default you would manually need to add them to your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

I think airline is too complex.
Here's my own config for the tabline.
[image]

(things like "term://.//30852:/usr/bin/zsh" is too ugly and annoying, so I make it short)

```
" buffers
    set hidden
    " If you want to keep the changed buffer (让vim记住它) without saving it(写到文件), switch on the
    " 'hidden' option.
    " nnoremap gb :bnext<CR>
    nno  gB :bprev<CR>



" tab
    " 导致卡死
    " au AG TabEnter * tabmove 0
    " au AG BufEnter * tabmove 0

    " normal模式下切换到确切的tab
        no  <leader>1 1gt
        no  <leader>2 2gt
        no  <leader>3 3gt
        no  <leader>4 4gt
        no  <leader>5 5gt
        no  <leader>6 6gt
        no  <leader>7 7gt
        no  <leader>8 8gt
        no  <leader>9 9gt

    " Toggles between the active and last active tab
        let g:last_active_TaB = 1
            " 只有一个tab时, 自然要取1
        nno <silent> <leader>t <Cmd>execute 'tabnext'  g:last_active_TaB<cr>
        vno <silent> <leader>t <Cmd>execute 'tabnext'  g:last_active_TaB<cr>
        au AG TabLeave * let g:last_active_TaB = tabpagenr()
        " tabpagenr(): 当前tab的序号

        set tabpagemax=12

        set switchbuf=usetab,newtab

" tabline:

    set showtabline=2
        " 1: only if there are at least two tab pages
        " 2: always

    func! Wf_tabline()
        hi Tab_icoN         guibg=#e0e5e3  gui=bold    guifg=#2f90b0
        hi Tab_icoN_Sel     guibg=#e0f6e3  gui=bold    guifg=#2f90b0

        hi TabLine          guibg=#e0e5e3  gui=none    guifg=#123456
        hi TabLineSel       guibg=#e0f6e3  gui=bold    guifg=#123456

        hi TabLineFill      guibg=#e0e5e3  gui=none    guifg=#e4e0e0

        hi LeoTab_separate  guibg=#e0e5e3  gui=none    guifg=#012345
        hi LeoTab_modified  guibg=#e0e5e3  gui=none    guifg=#0aafbb

        let a_tab = ''
        "\ for tab_id in range( tabpagenr('$')+1 )  导致多一个tab
        for i in range( tabpagenr('$') )
            let tab_id  = i + 1   " 第一个tab是1,而非0
            let winnr_in_tab = tabpagewinnr(tab_id)
                            " current window of tab page "tab_id"
            let bufLisT =  tabpagebuflist(tab_id)
                            " The result is a |List|,
                            "     each item is
                            "     the buffer number (see |bufnr()|) associated with each window
                            "     in the current tab page.
            let bufNuM       = bufLisT[ winnr_in_tab - 1 ]  " 当前tab的(首个窗口的?)buffer number
            let long_bufname = expand("#" . bufNuM . ":p")
                                   "\ #:  alternate file name
            let PwD  =  getcwd(winnr_in_tab,  tab_id)
            "\ let PwD  =  getcwd(bufNuM, tab_id)  \ 会错用当前tab的当前window?

            let a_tab .= (tab_id == tabpagenr() ?  '%#TabLineSel#' : '%#TabLine#')
                                " tab_page_number

            if  getbufvar(bufNuM, "&mod")
                let a_tab .=  ' + '
            el
                let a_tab .= ' '
            en


            if  long_bufname =~ "term:"
                         " 形如:term://~/dotF/cfg/nvim//809801:zsh
                          " =~   regexp matches (zsh里也是这样 不是~=, python里用regular模块吧 )
                          "      =~ 后, patter永远是magic的
                          " !~   regexp doesn't match

                "\ let PwD = substitute(getcwd(-1, tab_id-1)     , '^term://' , '' , '')
                "\ let PwD = substitute(PwD          , '//\d\+:.*', '' , '')
                "\ let a_list = split(PwD, '/')[-2:-1]

                let a_list = split(PwD, '/')[-2:-1]
                for _idx in range(len(a_list))
                    if len(a_list[_idx]) > 4
                        let a_list[_idx] = a_list[_idx][:3] . '·'
                                                          "\ 行中间点号
                    en
                endfor
                let PwD = join(a_list , '/')
                let a_tab .=  PwD
                "\ let a_tab .=  split(b:term_title, ' ')[0]  \ 导致many errors, because if the current buffer is not a
                        "\ term buffer, it can not access other buffer's b:term_title
                let a_tab .=  ' '

            elseif  long_bufname == ''
                if exists('w:quickfix_title')
                    let a_tab .=  w:quickfix_title[:10]
                el
                    if &buftype == 'quickfix'
                        let a_tab .=  'QuickFix'
                    el
                        let a_tab .=  '非file'
                    en
                en
            el
                " 取路径首字母
                if long_bufname    =~ 'after'    ||
                   \ long_bufname =~ 'plugin'   ||
                   \ long_bufname =~ 'autoload' ||
                   \ long_bufname =~ 'ftplugin' ||
                   \ long_bufname =~ 'syntax'

                    let p_nega_3 = split(long_bufname, '/')[-3][0:4]
                    let p_nega_2 = split(long_bufname, '/')[-2][0:4]

                    let PwD = join([p_nega_3,p_nega_2] , '/')
                    let a_tab .=  PwD . '/'
                en


                if long_bufname   =~ '\/arxivs\/'
                    let paper_name = split(long_bufname, '/')[-2][0:10]
                                                              " 文件名前10个字符
                    let a_tab .=  paper_name . '/'
                en


                if long_bufname =~ '\v\p+\.\p+$'  " 形如my_name.suffix

                    let f_namE = fnamemodify(long_bufname, ':t')
                    if f_namE =~ '\v\.\p+$'
                                " 用双引号, 无法用\a, \p 等 只能 [a-z]
                                    " \p printable

                        let icon = File_Icon(f_namE)
                                    " parameters: a:1 (filename), a:2 (isDirectory)
                                    " both parameters optional
                                    " by default without parameters uses buffer name

                        if icon != ''
                            " 扔掉后缀名
                            let a_tab .= f_namE ->substitute('\v\.\p{2,}$',  ' ',  '')
                                     "\ f_namE ->substitute("\v\.[a-z]",  '',  '')

                            let a_tab .= (tab_id == tabpagenr()
                                        \ ?  '%#Tab_icoN_Sel#'
                                        \ :  '%#Tab_icoN#' )
                            let a_tab .=  icon
                            let a_tab .= (tab_id == tabpagenr()
                                        \ ?  '%#TabLineSel#'
                                        \ :  '%#TabLine#' )
                        el
                            let a_tab .= f_namE
                        en
                    el
                        let a_tab .= f_namE

                    en

                el  " 没有后缀名
                    let tail = fnamemodify(long_bufname, ':t')
                    let a_tab .=   tail =~ '^\d\+$'
                                \ ? '[pre]'
                                \ : tail

                                  "\ pre表示preview?

                    let a_tab .=  ' '
                    let a_tab .=  File_Icon(long_bufname)
                en
            en

            let a_tab .= '%#LeoTab_separate#  '
        endfor

        let a_tab .= '%#TabLineFill#'
        return a_tab

    endfunc
    set tabline=%!Wf_tabline()



    " 改了不生效：
        " func! MyTab()
        "     let label = ''
        "     let bufnrlist = tabpagebuflist(v:lnum)
        "                                 " tab page number for 'guitablabel'
        "                                 "
        "     " Add '+' if one of the buffers in the tab page is modified
        "         for bufnr in bufnrlist
        "             if getbufvar(bufnr, "&modified")
        "                 let label = '+'
        "                 break
        "             endif
        "         endfor
        "
        "     if label != ''
        "         let label .= ' '
        "     endif
        "
        "     " Append the buffer name
        "     return label . bufname(bufnrlist[tabpagewinnr(v:lnum) - 1])
        " endfunc

        " set tabline=%!MyTab()
        " 笔记:
        "


" statusline
set laststatus=2  "  always show statusline
        " set laststatus=1  " only if there are at least two windows
        " 没有statusline时，命令那行和代码容易混在一起

" Each status line item is of the form: ( All fields except the {item} are optional.)
"       %-0{minwid}.{maxwid}{item}
    " 在上面的基础上：  (几表示某个highlight设置)
    " %Highlight配色号码






    hi   StatusLine     guibg=#d0e6d3   guifg=#000000   gui=none
    hi   StatusLineNC   gui=bold        guibg=#e0f0f0   guifg=#0099a0


    hi link Hi_status_1    StatusLine
    hi   Hi_status_2          guibg=#f5f5e3   guifg=#123456
    hi   Hi_status_3          guibg=#efe9d8   guifg=#123456
    hi   Hi_status_light      guibg=#eee9d9   guifg=#029456   gui=none
    hi   Hi_status_standout   guibg=#e0e6d3   guifg=#000000   gui=bold
        "\ 不再用了?:
            hi User0   guibg=none  guifg=#000000
            hi User1   guibg=none  guifg=#000000
            "\ 貌似不能放进colorscheme file.



    " statusline是个str, 竖线 空格都要escape

    " ¿%几*¿ 表示User几的highlight
    " ¿%#Your_highlight_name#¿ 可用正常的hi group


    " 改stl时 避免看晕:
        " syn match Set_status_linE  #\Vset stl+=#  conceal cchar=•

    set stl=   " 不加这行 会导致reload后stl很多重复
    set stl+=\ \ \ " space
    set stl+=%#Hi_status_standout#
    set stl+=%2l
    set stl+=%#Hi_status_1#
    set stl+=\ /%L行 " line number
                 " broken bar
    set stl+=\ \ ¦\ \ %2v\列 " 2表示 至少占2位
                " v    Virtual column number (screen column).
                " c    Column number (byte index) 2个中文之间差了3, 有点奇怪
    " set stl+=\ %F\ \     " File+path
    set stl+=%#Hi_status_2#
    set stl+=\ %{Status_f_namE()}\ \     " File+path

        fun! Status_f_namE()
            let file_with_icon = ''

            "\ 处理文件名
                let full_name = expand('%:p')

                if full_name =~ '\v' . '\p+\.\p+$'  " 有后缀名
                                       " \p printable
                                        " 如果用双引号, 无法用\a, \p 等 只能 [a-z]

                  let f_namE = fnamemodify(full_name, ':t')

                    if f_namE =~ '\v' . '\.\p+$'
                        let icon = File_Icon(f_namE)
                                  " parameters: a:1 (filename), a:2 (isDirectory)
                                  " both parameters optional
                                  " by default without parameters uses buffer name

                          if icon != ''
                              " 扔掉后缀名
                              let file_with_icon .= f_namE ->substitute('\v\.\p{2,}$',  ' ',  '')
                                              "\ f_namE ->substitute("\v\.[a-z]",  '',  '')

                              "\ 为啥不能像tabline那样?
                              "\ let file_with_icon .=    '%#Hi_status_3#'
                              let file_with_icon .=   icon
                              "\ let file_with_icon .=    '%#Hi_status_3#'

                          el
                              let file_with_icon  .= f_namE
                          en

                    el
                        let file_with_icon .= f_namE
                    en

                el  " 没有后缀名
                    let tail = fnamemodify(full_name, ':t')
                    let file_with_icon .=   tail =~ '^\d\+$' ?
                                            \ '[pre]'
                                            \ : tail
                    let file_with_icon .=  ' '
                    let file_with_icon .=  File_Icon(full_name)
                en

            "\ 避免显示的path太长
                let expand_path = expand('%:p:~:h')
                                      "\ 用~表示home

                if expand_path =~ "/arxivs"
                    let pieces = expand_path ->split('/arxivs')
                    let folder  = pieces[-1]
                    if  folder[0] == '/'
                        let folder = folder[1:]
                    en
                    let expand_path   = folder  ->substitute('_', ' ','g')
                    let expand_path   = expand_path[:40]

                elseif expand_path =~ 'dotF'
                    if expand_path == '~/dotF/cfg/nvim'
                        "\ 上面用了expand('%:p:~:h'),这样就不行:
                        "\ if expand_path == 'home/wf/dotF/cfg/nvim'
                        let expand_path   = ' '
                    elseif expand_path =~ '~/dotF/cfg/nvim/'  "\ 和上面重复? 不, 如果进了 上面的分支 就不会再进来
                        let pieces = expand_path ->split('~/dotF/cfg/nvim/')
                        if pieces[-1] =~ '/after/'
                            let pieces_2 =  split(pieces[-1], 'after')
                            let expand_path   = 'A ' . pieces_2[-1]
                        el
                            let expand_path   = ' ' . pieces[-1]
                                        "\ victory表示vim
                        en
                    el
                        let pieces = expand_path ->split('/dotF/')
                        let expand_path   = '⌂' . pieces[-1]
                    en

                elseif expand_path =~ '/.local/share/nvim/PL'
                    let pieces =  expand_path ->split('/.local/share/nvim/PL/')
                    let expand_path   = ' ' . pieces[-1]

                elseif  expand_path =~ '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/'
                    let pieces =  expand_path ->split('/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/')
                    "\ let expand_path   = ' ' . pieces[-1]
                    let expand_path   = 'צּ ' . pieces[-1]
                                  "\ homebrew

                elseif  expand_path =~ '/media/wf/data/large_wf/work/timm/pytorch-image-models/'
                    let pieces =  expand_path ->split('/media/wf/data/large_wf/work/timm/pytorch-image-models/')
                    "\ let expand_path   = ' ' . pieces[-1]
                    let expand_path   = 'IMM ' . pieces[-1]
                                  "\ homebrew


                elseif  expand_path =~ '/tT/wf_tex'
                    let expand_path   = '稳'
                    let pieces =  expand_path ->split('/tT/wf_tex/')

                    if len(pieces) > 1  | let expand_path  .=  pieces[-1]  | endif

                elseif  expand_path =~ '/\.trash/'
                    let pieces =  expand_path ->split('/.trash/')
                    let expand_path   = '' . pieces[-1]

                elseif  expand_path =~ '/\.t/'
                    let pieces =  expand_path ->split('/.t/')
                    let expand_path   = '' . pieces[-1]

                el

                    "\ 不改变expand_path
                en


                "\ echom expand_path[-1:]
                let last_char = expand_path[-1:]
                        "\     Use [-1:] to get the last byte.
                            "\ because a negative index   always results in an empty string ( backward compatibility).
                if last_char =~ '\f'
                \ || ( char2nr( last_char ) >= 19968 ) && ( char2nr( last_char ) <= 40869 )
                       "\ 加了这行还是无法处理中文
                    let expand_path .= '/'
                en

            return expand_path . file_with_icon . ''
        endf
    "\ set stl+=\ %{expand('%:h')}\ \     " File+path
    set stl+=\ \ %r\     " %r  readonly, 显示 [RO]
    set stl+=\ \ %w\     " Top/bot.
    "\ set stl+=%#Hi_status_3#
    set stl+=%{strftime('%H:%M')}
        "\ zsh下敲date, 显示中国格式的时间, 但这里还是慢了8小时
        "\ 就算设了LC_ALL 是zh_CN.UTF-8, 还是不行
        "\ 可能原因: brew的tzselect等命令 代替了apt管的命令. brew的glibc和 debian还不能完美共处?
        "\ solution: /home/wf/dotF/zsh/zshenv.zsh里  export TZ=Asia/Shanghai
        "\
    set stl+=%#Hi_status_2#



    " set stl+=\[buf号:%n]                  " buffer 号

    fun! Bad_news_coc() abort
        let bad_news = get(b:, 'coc_diagnostic_info', {})
            "   l表示local, 函数内的变量,可以省略
            " let l:bad_news = get(b:, 'coc_diagnostic_info', {})

        if empty(bad_news)
            return ''
        en

        let msgs = []
        if get(bad_news, 'error', 0)
            call add(msgs, '错误数:' . bad_news['error'])
        en

        if get(bad_news, 'warning', 0)
            call add(msgs, '警告数:' . bad_news['warning'])
        en

        return join(msgs, ' ') . ' ' . get(g:, 'coc_status', '')
    endfunc

    set stl^=%1*%{Bad_news_coc()}
    " 就算换行是CR NL  ,好像也没啥要特别注意的

    "\ coc的, 不知道影响哪里
        "\ set statusline+=%4*%{coc#status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}
        "\ fun! StatusDiagnostic() abort
        "\     let info = get(b:, 'coc_diagnostic_info', {})
        "\     if empty(info) | return '' | endif
        "\     let msgs = []
        "\     if get(info, 'error', 0)
        "\         call add(msgs, 'E' . info['error'])
        "\     en
        "\     if get(info, 'warning', 0)
        "\         call add(msgs, 'W' . info['warning'])
        "\     en
        "\     return join(msgs, ' ') . ' ' . get(g:, 'coc_status', '')
        "\ endf
        "\ set stl+=%1*%{StatusDiagnostic()}

    " 好像没啥用:
        " set stl+=\ \[
        " set stl+=%2*%{get(g:,'coc_git_status','')}
        " set stl+=\]
        " set stl+=%2*%{get(b:,'coc_git_status','')}

        " 插到开头
        "\ set stl+=\ %{&spelllang}\             " Spell language?



    " au AG BufWinEnter,WinEnter  term://* setl  stl=%9*%{'-\ '->repeat(30)}
    " au AG TermOpen  term://* setl  stl=%3*%{'-\ '->repeat(30)}
        " au AG TermEnter  * setl  stl=%!repeat('-', 10)  " 逗号后的空格, 要escape, 不然断开
        au AG TermEnter,TermOpen  *
                \   setl stl=%#Hi_status_2#
                "\ \ | setl stl+=%{hostname()}
                \ | setl stl+=%{repeat('-\ \ ',\ 5)}
                \ | setl stl+=%#Hi_status_3#
                \ | setl stl+=%{strftime('%H:%M')}
                \ | setl stl+=%#Hi_status_2#

                         " setl    stl=%9*%!repeat('-\ ',\ 10)  叹号出问题
                          " 加了这行, reload后, 敲i, stl不再那么乱了
        " 不生效:
        " au AG BufWinEnter,WinEnter  term://* setl  laststatus=0 | setglobal laststatus=2


        au AG BufNew,BufEnter  *  if bufname() == '[dap-repl]'      | setl stl=%#Hi_status_2#REPL  | endif
        au AG BufNew,BufEnter  *  if bufname() == 'DAP Stacks'      | setl stl=%#Hi_status_2#Stack | endif

        au AG BufNew  *  if bufname() == 'DAP Scopes'      | setl stl=%#Hi_status_2#scope | endif
        au AG BufNew  *  if bufname() == 'DAP Breakpoints' | setl stl=%#Hi_status_2#break | endif

        "\ au AG BufNew,BufEnter  *  if bufname() == ''                | setl stl=%#Hi_status_2#空      | endif
                                     "\ 这样用的是BufEnter前的bufname
```